# bash script not running at startup

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have created a simple bash script called echo.sh. Which outputs a string. I've made sure its executable. And i then added it to the "startup applications" program through the GUI interface. However when i reboot my machine, it doesn't appear to of been executed, as there is no echo appearing in a terminal.

from my understanding shouldn't the script ,when executed, open up a terminal automatically from my understanding because of the STDOUT being the terminal file. However the script works fine if i launch it myself from the terminal.

**echo.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello this is a bash script talking"
```

**Making it Executable**

```
chmod +x echo.sh
```

**Adding to "startup applications with correct directory to file"**
[image: /home/sam/Documents/bash/echo.sh]

**Outcome**

However when i reboot the system, the script doesn't run as expected, and no terminal appears with the echo message. I'm unsure as to why, and i may be completely missing the point, if so please let me know.

just to note, all my other bash scripts work , such as my "cleanup.sh" script which is also in the "startup applications" program.

**Attempted fixes**

I've tried redirecting the STDOUT to the terminal file /dev/tty. However this doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello this is a bash script talking" >/dev/tty
```

I've also tested a bash script with just a simple rm command, just to check if it was just the echo command that was having a problem. However when added to start up applications or .bashrc file, it doesn't delete the test.txt in the same directory as the script. However works when i execute manually from the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm ./test.txt
```

I've also tested startup applications program itself with just opening Firefox, with just the command Firefox. Which works without an issue. So their doesn't seem to be an issue with the startup applications program itself?

Comment: If you want to run this script during starting terminal add it to .bashrc file. Probably it runs at startup but you cannot see the output. You can check dmesg log, but I'm not sure if it's going to be there

Comment: Thanks for the response @mrc02_kr. However it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to avoid using relative paths in scripts. It leads to unexpected behavior and then a lot of debugging. Try to redirect echo to file: echo "bash script" > /root/test_bash.txt. Also tell us what do you want to achive ? Maybe it's a better way to do it?

Comment: Well my initial script, which called "sudo apt-get update" has similar issues. So i decided to try and start up a simple echo script. Which doesn't work. Which is really confusing as my cleanup.sh script works perfectly at boot up.

Comment: Don't run `apt-get update` at startup. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo) is tutorial how to automate apt updates.

Comment: noted, will check it out. However this still leaves the issue of my bash scripts still not running at startup.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting echo to file with absolute path? Show output of `ls -l $your_script_path`

Comment: Can you make clear the command entry (text) of your screenshot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [script running in crontab not giving output on shell screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210928/script-running-in-crontab-not-giving-output-on-shell-screen)

Comment: Define what you mean by "startup" - I don't use gnome but this looks like an xdg autostart config - it will run when you login, not when the machine starts.  And you won't see it running because it doesn't open a terminal

Answer (score 0):

The script probably works, but the STDOUT of the script (wherever the output is directed to) is connected to the process on your OS that is concerned with launching startup scripts like this, which does not run in a  terminal, but is a user hidden process within for example the kernel. To open up a terminal with this message you should probably edit it to

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e 'echo "hello this is a bash script talking"'
```

(I'm not on Ubuntu right now so can't test this, but the gist is to explicitly open a terminal where you want this message to show up in)

Comment: Thanks for the response, However this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What happens when you enter `gnome-terminal -e 'echo "hello this is a bash script talking"'`  in a terminal?

Comment: Executing it manually, it flashed opened up a window and quickly closed. Not sure if it was a terminal, however from the quick flash of an application appearing, it didn't look like a terminal. When added to the startup applications and rebooted,nothing occurred.

Comment: @Hexodus I suggest `gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo "hello this is a bash script talking";bash'` so-that you can examine.

Comment: ... or ad a `read` call to wait for the user to press Enter.

Comment: This won't work because at startup it's extremely unlikely anyone will (yet) be logged in, so there will be nowhere to launch the gnome terminal. Then there are other issues around authentication to display on a logged in user's graphical session

Answer (score 0):

You can check the config file of the autostart file you created with

```bsh
cat ~/.config/autostart/NAME.desktop
```

If you want to execute your script in a terminal you should add
`Terminal=true`
to the file.
You can also set `Hidden=false` accordingly to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

The simples method use the crontab like so;

```
crontab -e
```

Add your script at the of the contrab file

```
#
@reboot /path-to-your-script/your-script-name.sh
```

Then reboot to observe the change

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, it does not seem that the OP has a problem adding the script to the `crontab`, but rather that the OP expects to see _console output from a script run via `crontab`_ which doesn't happen (for several reasons).

Answer (score -1):

You should add `/bin/bash -c` in front of your `'/path/to/your/script.sh'`

```
/bin/bash -c '/path/to/your/script.sh'
```

The `echo` command output will be visible in your system logs, not in your terminal.

`journalctl -b` will show you the output of system boot logs, which is when your script is run.