# Shell script does not run at desktop startup

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a simple script that I want to run at startup but it doesn't get run.
The script is simple, it just swaps right Option key with right CMD key on my Apple Magic Keyboard:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Super_R"
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

When I run the script from the terminal it works fine. It doesn't work at startup. I have added an entry to Startup Application like this.
[image]

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 with X11 with passwordless login so I want the keys to be swapped after my desktop shows up.

```
type Xorg
Xorg is /usr/bin/Xorg
```

Why doesn't it work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related? [bash script not running at startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/377702/100397)

Comment: Not really. I saw this.

Comment: I used to have a similar script and it worked fine. I have automatic login to my Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you intend this to run at system startup, when the GUI login manager starts, or when you log in with your account?

Comment: I want it to run after my desktop shows up.

Comment: A shot in the dark, but if you're using a recent Ubuntu version you may be using Wayland as your display server and AFAIK xmodmap is X only and won't run on Wayland.

Comment: I am running 21.10 and by default it uses X11.

Comment: I am not sure; but in recent versions my scrips using xmodmap no long work. I had to switch to `gesttings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources source "[('xkb','...')]"`

Comment: @JJoao not related to my question